# Can not dismiss Modal View Controller with ios5

Tags: ios5, ios6

I present one controller to play video:

```
  [self presentModalViewController:movieController animated:YES];
```

and add an observer when finish palying:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedPlayback:) 
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    }

    -(void) movieFinishedPlayback:(NSNotification*)notification{
        NSLog(@"........movieFinishedPlayback....... \n ");
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    }
```

This my VideoDetailViewController:

```
#import "VideoDetailViewController.h"
#import "PSStackedView.h"
#import "YunMaoIpadAppDelegate.h"

#define IpadAppDelegate ((YunMaoIpadAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
#define IphoneAppDelegate ((YunMaoIosAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

@interface VideoDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoDetailViewController

@synthesize video, moviePlayer, collectionsArray;

-(id)initWithVideo:(Video *)theVideo
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"VideoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        self.video = theVideo;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [moviePlayer pause];
    //[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:false animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //[moviePlayer play];
    //[DejalBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(displayActivityView) withObject:self.moviePlayer.view afterDelay:0.1];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:video.link]];
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

    //[moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

    if([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(useApplicationAudioSession)])
    {
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            NSLog(@"iPhone ios5.x");
            [moviePlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f)];
            //moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moviePlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"iPad ios5.x");
            [moviePlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f)];
            moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moviePlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));
            [moviePlayer.view setFrame:[IpadAppDelegate window].bounds];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            moviePlayer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(moviePlayer.view.transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2));

            NSLog(@"iPhone ios6.x");
            CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
            if(result.height == 480)
            {
                [moviePlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
            }
            if(result.height == 568)
            {
                //moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
                [moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
            }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"ipad ios 6.x");
            [moviePlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f)];
            //[moviePlayer.view setFrame:[IpadAppDelegate window].bounds];
        }
    }

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer play];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

/*
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
*/

- (IBAction)displayActivityView
{
    [DejalBezelActivityView activityViewForView:self.moviePlayer.view withLabel:@"节目正在下载中，请稍后..."].showNetworkActivityIndicator = NO;
}

- (void)removeActivityView;
{
    [DejalBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
    [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Notice, that you are adding an observer for `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` but are removing an observer for `MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification`. Is this the intended action?

Comment: Update question and still can not work.

Comment: One critical piece of info you left out... Does your log statement appear in the console? Also, simulator or device?

Comment: I update the detail view controller. It seems like when run `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`, the app go back to the home page and the screen is black.

Comment: @why, Before dismissing movieplayer do `[moviePlayer stop];` and remove movieplayer.view from superview. Try dismissing after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Before dismissing movieplayer do `[moviePlayer stop];` and remove `movieplayer.view` from superview. Try dismissing after that. That might fix the issue.